# No result with r plotly::plot_mapbox() on a sf dataset

Tags: r, plotly

I have a sf dataset that only has a geometry attribute (no lat, long) as shown below. It has line features (representing roads). I can create a map using geom_sf(comb), but I don't get any result with plotly::plot_mapbox(comb). Am I missing something? Are there other interactive libraries that could plot sf?

NOTE: I have a mapbox token key; this question is crossposted on rstudio community website also.

```
> comb
Simple feature collection with 1332 features and 8 fields
geometry type:  MULTILINESTRING
dimension:      XYM
bbox:           xmin: 1272518 ymin: 5288000 xmax: 2833314 ymax: 6437275
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=44.5 +lat_2=53.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-85 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
# A tibble: 1,332 x 9
   lhrs  nearest_weather~ location days_rained days_snowed
   <chr>            <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 10004             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 2 10008             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 3 10011             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 4 10014             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 5 10017             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 6 10022             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 7 10025             4635 FORT ER~          18           4
 8 10030             4684 ST CATH~           3           2
 9 10032             4684 ST CATH~           3           2
10 10040             4684 ST CATH~           3           2
# ... with 1,322 more rows, and 4 more variables:
#   DESCRIPTIO <fct>, HWY <chr>, Shape_STLe <dbl>,
#   geometry <MULTILINESTRING [m]>
```

Comment: `dimension:      XYM` looks interesting. `XYM` means there is an extra `M` value at each vertex. Perhaps `plot_mapbox` is failing because of this? Any chance you can dump your data somewhere we can get it?

Comment: Also, either don't crosspost or please give the link to the post elsewhere so we can see if its been fixed there and we don't waste our time fixing it here.

Comment: You were right about the additional `M`. Using `st_zm()` resolves the issue when I use `mapview` library. I didn't have a chance yet to try `plotly::plot_mapbox()` again.